# Modify types of package? (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, package, phaser-framework

I'm trying to modify a package type so it fits my needs but nothing I try seems to work.

I'm calling a function that creates a text on a scene of Phaser.
This is possible by doing:

```js
this.ctx.add.text(x,y, string, TextStyle)
```

The problem I'm facing is that I need TextStyle to have more properties or accept different types on the ones it already has and can't find where to modify it.

On phaser type definitions I found this:

```js
// phaser.d.ts

declare namespace Phaser {
  namespace GameObject {
    class GameObjectFactory {
      text(x: number, y: number, text: string | string[], style?: Phaser.Types.GameObjects.Text.TextStyle): Phaser.GameObjects.Text;
    }
  }
}
```

So I can assume that I have to modify `Phaser.Types.GameObjects.Text.TextStyle` right?
I searched for the types and found this:

```
// phaser.d.ts

declare namespace Phaser {
  namespace Types {
    namespace GameObjects {
      namespace Text {
        type TextStyle = {
          // ... all the properties it already has
          // HERE I would like to modify
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I declared the following:

```
// vite-env.d.ts

declare global {
  namespace Phaser {
    namespace Types {
      namespace GameObjects {
        namespace Text {
          type TextStyle = {
            hello: number
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[But it stills doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp4oA.png)

However I tried [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLcHG.png) and got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUZ8u.png) . (also tried what's commented but didn't work)

I must be somehow close but since I'm such a noob with Typescript can't figure it out by myself.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the type-definitions is not a good idea.
You could simply extend the `TextStyle` type and then *cast* a created object to the new type.

**Something like:**

```
interface TestTextStyle extends Phaser.GameObjects.TextStyle {
    hello: number
}

class TestScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    create(){
        this.add.text(1,1,'Hello World', {hello: 1} as TestTextStyle)
    }
}
```

**Or simply** ignore that one specific line:

```
class TestScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    create(){
        // @ts-ignore
        this.add.text(1,1,'Hello World', {hello: 1} )
    }
}
```

Nevertheless I don't understand, why you need the extra property, because Phaser won't use it.

> **Info:** *(from the comments)* obviously you cannot override the type of a property(in this manner), that already exists in the base typedefinition.

**Demo `fontSize` is a string:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    }
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'DEMO TEXT',{fontSize: '16px'})
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
        
    this.add.text(10,40, 'DEMO TEXT',{fontSize: '32px'})
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    this.add.text(10,90, 'DEMO TEXT',{fontSize: '64px'})
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: The thing is that the package type definitions is asking for a string in "fontSize" but it doesn't work with a string. It works with numbers. And when I put a number typescript complains. That's why I was looking for a polite way of fixing it.

Comment: I did what you suggest and this is the result: 
interface TestTextStyle

Conversion of type '{ fontSize: number; }' to type 'TestTextStyle' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ fontSize: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TextStyle': parent, fontFamily, fontStyle, backgroundColor, and 51 more.ts(2352)

Comment: @LeFede well if you are overriding an existing property, this won't work (since conflicting types). creating **new** properties can work like this. But I still don't understand the problem, `fontSize` is a string (I updated my answer)

Comment: I want to be able to put { fontSize: 16 } without typescript errors using the method this.add.text(). That's the main point of this post. You think it's possible?

Comment: Well `fontSize` is a string, can't you put `{ fontSize: '16px' }` or if it should be a variable you could do `{ fontSize: \`${value}px\`  }`?

Comment: If you want, to be able to pass a number _(what might cause problems)_, you are wright you would have to change the definition file, but also the javascript code _(if you want to be sure it work as it should)_. And honestly I would really not recommend this, since you would have to do this on every phaser update, or fork the project. But for that very specific, task I can't help.